# Perl doesn't recognise the non-ascii character

Tags: perl, encoding, character-encoding

I have `*TXT` file with Non-ASCII characters for e.g.`é ê ù`. However `*TXT` file mode is in `ANSI` (Default mode).

I am using in Perl `utf8` for reading the Non-ASCII characters and converting into `hexadecimal entities`.

The problem is if the `*TXT` file having `ANSI` mode then the Perl doesn't work, however the `*TXT` mode is in `utf8` then the script is working without problem.

Perl:

```
use open ':encoding(utf8)';
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

...


#assume $amatch contains non-ascii characters 
$amatch = ord($amatch);
$amatch = sprintf("&#x%x;", $amatch);
```

Do anyone have solution for this?

Comment: You don't show how you open and read data from the specific file. But, in case you read from STDIN you explicitly set in the first line of the code you show that you expect the data to be UTF8 encoded - in which case it of course fails if the data are not UTF8 encoded.

Comment: I am sure promise not clear with you

Comment: Tip: The name of the well-used encoding is "UTF-8". "UTF8" is something else you don't want.

Comment: Somebody is roaming for giving downvote without reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's not UTF-8, of course it won't work if you tell Perl it's UTF-8!

The "ANSI" encoding of your machine can be obtained by prepending `cp` to the number returned by `Win32::GetACP()`.

```
use Win32 qw( );
my $ansi_enc = "cp".Win32::GetACP();
open(my $fh, "<:encoding($ansi_enc)", $qfn)  # File encoded using machine's ANSI encoding.
```

as opposed to

```
open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", $qfn)  # File encoded using UTF-8.
```

Comment: how can I find ascii and convert to Unicode entities

Comment: `while($tmp=~m/[^[:ascii:]]/sg) {  print ": $&\n";  }` not found non-ascii characters.

Comment: Could you please help on this one.

Comment: Re "*how can I find ascii and convert to Unicode entities*", I have no idea what you mean by that

Comment: Re "*not found non-ascii characters*", so? Is this new highly incomplete question? The comments are not for that